# Can't install packages in pycharm, errno2

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I tried to install pandas through pycharm but then it said this, i then try with numpy but it yield the same problem:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.25.0.tar.gz (10.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [40 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      backend = _build_backend()
    File "C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
      obj = import_module(mod_path)
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1b4ajfja\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 242, in <module>
      monkey.patch_all()
    File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1b4ajfja\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 99, in patch_all
      patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
    File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1b4ajfja\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 162, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
      patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
    File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1b4ajfja\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 149, in patch_params
      mod = import_module(mod_name)
    File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "C:\Users\kirit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-1b4ajfja\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
      raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

They told me to copy this command in terminal:

```
C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\bin\activate.bat
C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\bin\python.exe C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install numpy
```

i tried but then it yielded:

```
C:\Users\kirit\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\bin\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

my checked my pip with the command they provided and it's currently the latest version (23.1.2). I don't know what to do know, can anyone help me? My biggest thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: try to open pycharm as administrator

Hi, this problem occurs because pycharm is installed in `Program Files`, where there is a space after "Program" and trying to call the `C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm...`
command, an error is caused that says it cannot find the directory `C:\\Programm` I once had this error, the solution I found was to install dependencies through the console. It may not be so convenient, but this way you will be sure what is happening and what commands are being called

Comment: thanks for your help! I just fixed the problem by choosing another interpreter (mingw64 to python). Though i don't really know why xD

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by choosing another interpreter (accidentally, i love my luck), at first I choose mingw64. I'll post it here so that if anyone got the same problem, it may help them a bit. Thank you guys!

Edit: the problem is caused by a space in the path to the interpreter
[image]